# Why does my gitlab-ci.yml keep crashing on npm run test, while it works in the code editor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gitlab, mocha.js, pipeline

I have written tests for my code and they all pass. I use nodejs to make a REST api. I decided to commit everything to a gitlab repository. This all worked. I then added the gitlab-ci.yml file to my project. It currently looks like this:

```
stages:
    - testing

Testing:
    stage: testing
    image: node:latest
    services:
        - mongo:latest
    before_script:
        - npm install --no-optional
    script:
        - npm run test
```

Im fairly new to pipelines, and i am not sure whats wrong with it. I use MongoDB for my data base and my connection string is located in a .env file. The tests are written using mocha and chai.
When I commit, the pipeline fails. I get the error:

```
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

When I look further in the error it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/UserController'
```

This is strange because im not getting this error in my code editor (Visual Code), and the file UserController is located in the controllers folder.
I feel like the gitlab-ci.yml is missing something, but I cant figure out what it is. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I use MongoDB for my data base and my connection string is located in a .env file.

If your application is configured dynamically this might be the issue (I'm supposing **you're not committing secrets to version control**), make sure to go to your `Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables`, click on `Add Variables` and put the contents of your `.env` file in it, make sure to select `File` as the type.

[image: Setting up a variable]

Gitlab doesn't allow the name `.env` as a valid name, so make sure to use some other value, like `ENV`.

```yaml
stages:
    - testing

Testing:
    stage: testing
    image: node:latest
    services:
        - mongo:latest
    before_script:
        # ENV is exported as a path to your "ENV" file, 
        # this is copying it to a local '.env' file
        - cp $ENV .env
        # If you need it, this is a way to export the
        # environment variables inside your file
        - source .env; export $(cut -d= -f1 .env);
        # Debugging the pipelines
        - ls -lah
        # Your old commands
        - npm install --no-optional
    script:
        - npm run test
```

You can add more "debug" scrips to the `before_script` or `scripts` sections (like the `ls` one), this will help you to eventually catch what's going wrong on your pipelines.

Remark: If you don't want to add an entire file to CI, you can add the connection string separately as `Variable` types.

Answer (score 0):

other thing that can be happening is that you run different node & npm on gitlab then locally. I would make sure those are in sync & GitLab doesn't update randomly - ie, I would set `node:16` or what ever version you are sure runs ok.